# Python heapq replace priority

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm using Python's heapq. The algorithm requires changing a cell's value if a shorter path is discovered leading to it.

I'm doing that with this check:

```
if curr_cell[0] + val < prev_cell[0]:  # value of new path is less than old value
    new_cell = (curr_cell[0] + val, prev_cell[1], curr_cell[1])
    heap[index] = new_cell
    heapify(heap)
```

However, when running my program on a larger maze this is taking a long time, probably because of the `heapify()` call.

What's a more efficient way of changing the priority of a heap's entry?

Answer (score 13):

The heapq library doesn't support updating priorities efficiently because there is no efficient way to search the heap. If you search the heap in O(n) time and manually replace the element, you can then use _siftup() and _siftdown() to restore the heap invariant.

Alternatively, here is a compatible implementation I wrote which uses a dict to allow O(1) lookups of heap indexes.

https://github.com/elplatt/python-priorityq

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution is to mark the entry as removed and add a new entry with the revised priority. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) provides an example implementation:

```
pq = []                         # list of entries arranged in a heap
entry_finder = {}               # mapping of tasks to entries
REMOVED = '<removed-task>'      # placeholder for a removed task
counter = itertools.count()     # unique sequence count

def add_task(task, priority=0):
    'Add a new task or update the priority of an existing task'
    if task in entry_finder:
        remove_task(task)
    count = next(counter)
    entry = [priority, count, task]
    entry_finder[task] = entry
    heappush(pq, entry)

def remove_task(task):
    'Mark an existing task as REMOVED.  Raise KeyError if not found.'
    entry = entry_finder.pop(task)
    entry[-1] = REMOVED

def pop_task():
    'Remove and return the lowest priority task. Raise KeyError if empty.'
    while pq:
        priority, count, task = heappop(pq)
        if task is not REMOVED:
            del entry_finder[task]
            return task
    raise KeyError('pop from an empty priority queue')
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand the usage of itertools.count(). I don't quite understand it.

Comment: `itertools.count()` simply yields consecutive numbers. Adding the count to an entry like `[priority, count, task]` insures that entries with the same priority are processed in the order that they were added. I guess, you can skip it for the Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I already checked this in the official documentation but I have a question. Doesn't this implementation cost you in terms of the size of the heap? If you are updating priorities very often, isn't this going to make the heap size very large? Is there a more efficient way of doing this using private methods from heapq?

Comment: @SilverSlash: Yes, it does, but memory is cheap :) You could also do it in `O(log n)` time w/o inserting a new item to the heap using private `_siftup()` / `_siftdown()` functions, but that would require you to maintain positions of each item in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I wrote one just for this a couple of years ago that you might find useful!

https://pypi.org/project/priorityq/

Answer (score 0):

@elplatt's answer about using a dictionary and then using `_siftdown/_siftup` is a good one. Here's another implementation: https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/master/recipes/Python/577892_Dijkstrshortest_path/recipe-577892.py

Comment: array.index take O(n) time .... where is the advantage to use with sifting ? Dijkstra's algorithm pretend a O(log n) update function.

Answer (score -2):

heapify() routine provided by heapq takes linear time.

So instead of using heapify() which costs O(n) every time you change the priority, you should use data structure in which you can change the priority of that record and heapify occurs in O(logn).

You can use PriorityQueue provided by Queue.

Comment: PriorityQueue does not support deleting items or changing priorities.